# Check for sufficient number of tokens left

Tags: plain-tex, arguments

I want to use a command that takes a large number of arguments, possibly more than left in the input stream.

```
\def\consumeseven#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{}
\consumeseven
\space
```

In this scenario `\consumeseven` will see `\space` as its first argument and then complain that the "file ended while scanning use of \consumeseven".

Can something be done about this? Is there a way to check if there is a sufficient number of arguments left in the input stream?

---

### How did I come up with this? (Use Case)

I am experimenting with `\obeylines` to scan the source code of the main document for indentation. To do so, I would like to `\def` `^^M` (the newline character) to examine the first few tokens of a line. But this leads to failure when the last active newline is processed as this line only has one token, `\end`. I know that I could scan the whole document into a single argument delimited by `\end` and append some bogus tokens there or scan the file line by line. But I pondered whether it would be possible to alternatively guard a macro against the end of the file generally, and thus asked this question.

Comment: no `\end` is the first argument (white space  is ignored here)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Correct. It seems I had too much `\obeylines` lately...

Comment: Is there a use case for this?

Comment: @egreg There is now.

Answer (score 3):

Just with three arguments, to show the idea.

[image]

Read the arguments one at a time.

```
\def\consumethree#1{%
\def\arga{?}\def\argb{?}\def\argc{?}%
\ifx\end#1%
\message{stopping}\consume\expandafter\end
\else
\def\arga{#1}
\expandafter\consumetwo
\fi
}

\def\consumetwo#1{%
\ifx\end#1%
\message{stopping}\consume\expandafter\end
\else
\def\argb{#1}
\expandafter\consumeone
\fi
}

\def\consumeone#1{%
\ifx\end#1%
\message{stopping}\consume\expandafter\end
\else
\def\argc{#1}
\expandafter\consume
\fi
}

\def\consume{[\arga][\argb][\argc]}

\consumethree a b c

\consumethree a
\end
```

Comment: It wouldn't work if `\bye` is used instead of `\end`

Comment: @egreg I know, but the idea of the site is that you answer the questions asked, not all possible questions. If **you** ask a question on detecting `\bye` I'll answer it for you:-)

Comment: I would actually like to request that, as there are many ways to signal the end of a TeX or LaTeX document. Apart from `\bye` and `\end{document}`, `\end` may be hidden within an arbitrarily named macro. The file may even end without any of these commands. So I am more interested in detecting the end of file instead of a token that signals it.

Comment: @XZS do you really need to be doing this in the main document? Normally for any such token based parsing you can have it in an external file and use `\read` rather than `\input` and then testing for the end is built in there is an `\ifeof` primitive to test the end of file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle having an `\ifeof` available indeed would help. I just added the use case that led to my question. This may explain why I am reluctant to defer to `\read`.